# WPF - DatePicker calendar position

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I have an issue with this WPF DatePicker calendar popup position on Windows 8.1 tablet.
The issue starts when I click out from TextBox to DatePicker icon to select a date in that time tablet-tip aka keyboard disappears then opens up DatePicker calendar popup and overlaps DatePicker control as it is and that looks ugly...
Maybe someone has or had the same issue and knows how to fix that position problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly set focus on your textbox(through code behind) and then the keyboard and the app adjusts correctly.

Comment: do you know how to do that and maybe can share the solution? Thanks!

Comment: You need to call the focus property of your textbox. eg  this.txtName.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);

Comment: But the above code used to Focus fails sometimes. So try to call the textchanged event programmatically to set the focus correctly if the above code doesnt work.